# Are these distributions quantiles different? statistical significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance

I have an experimental distribution and I am looking at the quantiles. For example the counts for the quantiles are [10, 20, 40, 10, 20] respectively and I want to know if they differs from a uniform random distribution with counts like [20,20,20,20,20].

- What test should I perform?
- I am particularly interested in checking if the first quantile is significantly different. What test should I perform for this?

Note: Since the experimental data is sampled every year I actually have a distribution defined each year. This is basically a 'bootstrap', and maybe the uncertainty can be defined from the IQR for each quantile?

Comment: You really need to be more specific.  Which quantiles? Note also that notions of heavy-tailedness do not necessarily mean "more probability in the tails." See here for a family of distributions that have increasing kurtosis while the probability in the tails *decreases*.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523606/472987

Comment: (+1) for belated explanation and context in Comments.

Comment: I changed the text so that I don't mention "fat tails". I am not interested in fat tails but how much different the quantiles (in this case quintiles) are. Not sure how specific I can be regarding the quantiles...

Comment: @whuber. As I recall, some details have been added to this question and in comments. This is no longer exactly the question I tried to answer. To avoid possible confusion, probably best to delete Answer.

Comment: Depending on (a) how you chose those quantiles and (b) what this uniform distribution represents (observations or a theoretical reference), some version of a chi-squared test would be the obvious solution.  We would need to hear about these details before being able to offer specific advice.